# The Input number do not select a card

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

So i am building this deck of cards, but when i type af number in the textarea in HTML, it does not return the card from the array 'hjerter' 
It is supossed to to pick the from the number that has been typed into the textarea of the HTML, and then display the given card on the HTML page.

```js
function visKort() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Nr").value;
  var hjerter = ['h-ace', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'h7', 'h8', 'h9', 'h10', 'h-jack', 'h-queen', 'h-king'];

  var kort = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < hjerter.length; i++) {
    if (x == hjerter[i]) {

    } else if (i > 0) {
      break;
    }
    kort += "Nr " + x + "<br>" + "Dit kort er " + hjerter[i];
  }
  document.getElementById("vis_kort").innerHTML = kort;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <main>
    <h1>Kortspil til opgave 2</h1>
    <h2>Indtast nr på kort<br></h2>
    <textarea id="Nr">
        </textarea>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="visKort()">Vis mit kort</button> <br>
    <p id="vis_kort"><br>
  </main>
</center>
```

Comment: What is the `if else if` supposed to do? The first `if` will only match if the textarea contains the string `h-ace` (and then do nothing), and the second will break the loop after the first round. Hence it will always print `Nr [whatever you've entered] <br> Dit kort er h-ace` in the first round and then stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The way your loop is written, it will always append the first card and then break on the second card. You need to compare `x` (the chosen number) with `i` (the index in the deck) and only set the text if they match. However, this is kind of redundant - you can just access the deck using `x` directly. See below:

```js
function visKort() {
  var x = Number(document.getElementById("Nr").value);
  var hjerter = ['h-ace', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'h7', 'h8', 'h9', 'h10', 'h-jack', 'h-queen', 'h-king'];

  document.getElementById("vis_kort").innerHTML = "Nr " + x + "<br>" + "Dit kort er " + hjerter[x-1];
}
```

```html
<center>
  <main>
    <h1>Kortspil til opgave 2</h1>
    <h2>Indtast nr på kort<br></h2>
    <textarea id="Nr">
        </textarea>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="visKort()">Vis mit kort</button> <br>
    <p id="vis_kort"><br>
  </main>
</center>
```